# Oracle Web Services Security: WSSecurity sign throws NoSuchMethodError. How to find library issue

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, oracle11g, nosuchmethoderror

I am working with an Oracle 11g database (thus JDK 1.5) and trying to call a webservice with SOAP. I have to use ws-security, so I followed this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/security.1111/e10037/wss.htm

I did everything in the document, and it works locally (using Netbeans JDK 1.5). But when I try to run it on the Oracle 11g database (using SQL Developer), it throws a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on the sign method of WSSecurity. I use the same libraries at both locations (the ones mentioned in the documentation (saaj-api-1.3 and saaj-impl-1.3)).

What I found when googling is that it has to be a library issue, but I can't seem to figure out where it goes wrong. Does anybody have any idea where or how it can go wrong, or how I can find out?

The stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
at oracle.security.xmlsec.wss.WSSecurity.sign(WSSecurity.java:1169)
at Discimus.generateSoapMessage(DISCIMUS:176)
```

The relevant code:

```
...
WSSecurity ws = WSSecurity.newInstance(soapEnvelope);
...
WSSignatureParams params = new WSSignatureParams(null, privateKey);
String []uris = {"#Body"};
ws.sign(uris, params, null);    //Error throws here
```

As you can see, the stack trace seems to be missing a line: where in the sign method the error is actually thrown. Very weird, how can I get this missing line? Otherwise it's searching for a needle in a haystack.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` includes a description which gives the signature of the missing method (e.g. see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103374/formatting-a-simple-string-but-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror), top line of the error message).  What does yours say in this case?  I'm guessing you're missing a security provider JAR but without knowing *what* can't be found, it's hard to say.

Comment: Well that's the problem, it doesn't show that line (I edited my post and now show the full stacktrace as given by ex.printStackTrace).