# Oracle 11g: stack trace java error misses first line

Tags: java, oracle11g, nosuchmethoderror

I am working with an Oracle 11g database and trying to make a Java file work. I get an error when I try to run it (using SQL developer), and when I output the stack trace it is not complete.

My stack trace is:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
      at oracle.security.xmlsec.wss.WSSecurity.sign(WSSecurity.java:1169)
      at Discimus.generateSoapMessage(DISCIMUS:176)

I have a library issue somewhere, but I can't figure out where it is if I can't get a full stack trace. The sign method is large, so I need to know where the error is thrown.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have [you asked the same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19177307/266304) but with less detail?

Comment: I added the extra question there later on, but I thought it was worth a new separate question as it's not really directly related.